# Covert long row into multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have a ROW like below and

```
ID1 Name1   ID2 Name2   ID3 Name3
1     ABC   2    DEF    3   GHI
```

Expected output is like below, Do you have any option in SQL to do this in simple way,

```
ID  Name
1   ABC
2   DEF
3   GHI
```

I am doing this with writing up CTE and insert. The reason is I have similar source table where ID will go till 12,13.

Comment: Can you give sample input and expected output

Comment: you question is not clear...

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  SQL Server's `UNPIVOT` function would help here.  If not, then you might be looking at doing a `UNION` query.

Answer (score 1):

The `union all` will do what you want here

```
CREATE TABLE #tmptab1 (ID1 varchar(1) ,
                       Name1 varchar(3),   
                       ID2 varchar(1), 
                       Name2 varchar(3),  
                       ID3 varchar(1), 
                       Name3 varchar(3))

INSERT INTO #tmptab1 VALUES ('1','ABC','2','DEF','3','GHI')

SELECT ID1,Name1 
FROM #tmptab1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID2,Name2
FROM #tmptab1
UNION ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select id1 as id, name1 as name from t union all
select id2, name2 from t union all
select id3, name3 from t;
```